# JUnit - Using the Wrong Assert

Tags: unit-testing, junit

I quote this post from [exubero's](http://www.exubero.com/junit/antipatterns.html#Misuse_of_Assertions) entry. I think this entry will benefit everyone who is doing a unit test:

There are a large number of different methods beginning with assert defined in Junit's Assert class. Each of these methods has slightly different arguments and semantics about what they are asserting.

The following shows some irregular uses of assertTrue:

```
assertTrue("Objects must be the same", expected == actual);
assertTrue("Objects must be equal", expected.equals(actual));
assertTrue("Object must be null", actual == null);
assertTrue("Object must not be null", actual != null);
```

Some unit testing experts pointed out that the above code could be better written as:

```
assertSame("Objects must be the same", expected, actual);
assertEquals("Objects must be equal", expected, actual);
assertNull("Object must be null", actual);
assertNotNull("Object must not be null", actual);
```

One of the advantage of using the appropriate 'assertXXX()' will increase the readability of the unit test. Can anyone point out what other benefit of using the appropriate 'assertXXX()' ?

Comment: This is not a blog. Please don't post rants here, and then tack on a minor question at the end.

Comment: Noted on that. fair enough. I edited the wordings in the post. I never meant this question as 'rant'. My observation poses an interesting debate that can help every one to better write a unit test. So I just would like to see what other think about it.

Comment: It isn't really a debate, is it?  You should only use `assertTrue` for the specific case where testing a boolean method.  What's the issue?  Did you meet someone who was confused by assertTrue?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

I'm not a Java developer and I don't know what JUnit outputs when an assertion fails.
Many unit testing frameworks that I've been using output better error information when use something like assertEquals.

Let me show you an example what I'm talking about:

```
assertTrue("Objects must be equal", "One" == "Two");
assertEquals("Objects must be equal", "One", "Two");
```

In first case you can have an error output like this:

Error: Expected true actual was false.

Output for the second case:

Error: Exected "One" actual was "Two".

As you can see the second case gives better more meaningful information.

Comment: Hey vadim thank you for pointing this one out. You're completely right. Using assertEquals() will give a better output when there is an error compare to assertTrue().

Answer (score 0):

In addition to what @Vadim daid above, using the proper assert may guard against bugs created by cut-copy-paste of tests.

As an example

```
assertTrue("Objects must not be the same", expected != actual);
```

Is then copied and modified to

```
assertTrue("Objects must not be the same", newobject == actual);
```

When the code changes and this test fails and the comment fools the next developer to "fix" the code in a way that introduces a new bug.

If the cut-copy-paste-code was something like this:

```
assertFalse("Objects must be the same", newobject == actual);
```

The dis-congruity of the comment, the assertion and the test case may be more noticeable.

And yes, I've seen this happen.